# Grid.js Advanced Table Plugin - Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gridjs"

Tags: javascript, import, grid

I created a table using [grid.js](https://gridjs.io/), but now I'm trying to insert a button in the rows as specified in the [documentation](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/row-buttons). I tried this to import the h function:

```js
import { Grid, h } from "gridjs";
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gridjs"
```

I'm using only js files without any framework